# gradient at two edges of a layout android

Tags: android, android-layout

I have a layout file with multiple views inside. I want to keep the layout inside a box with shadow effect at bottom and right edges. I can make use of a 9 patch images with gradient at the two edges for this. But I want to avoid using images for this. I wrote a shape file to get box effect,

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >

        <size
            android:height="10dp"
            android:width="10dp" />

        <solid android:color="#FFFFFF" />

        <stroke
            android:width="1dp"
            android:color="@color/divider_color" />

    </shape>
```

How to get the gradient(shadow) at the two edges? as shown,

[image]